# SharePoint REST Get User Title in a single REST query

Tags: rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have a list which has a "People and Group" column. when I query the rows using REST, I get user Ids listed in this column.

I found this article which will help me in converting each id to a title

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/692289/How-to-Get-Login-Name-and-Display-Name-using-Sha

But I am wondering if there is a way in which I can get the user title by a single REST call (rather than first get the ID and then making another call to convert the ID into the user display name and the login name)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Using `$expand` OData operator you can specify that the request returns projected fields from other lists and the values of lookups.

The following REST endpoint:

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Pages')/items(1)?$select=Author/Name,Author/Title&$expand=Author/Id
```

returns `Title` and `Name` for `Author` column in Pages list

```
{
    "d": {
        "__metadata": {
            "id": "63b9e943-6398-4b6d-acc9-fc4f554f78df",
            "uri": "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/_api/Web/Lists(guid'be43ccf2-5ca7-4957-bf81-7cdc86744d9b')/Items(1)",
            "etag": "\"6\"",
            "type": "SP.Data.PagesItem"
        },
        "Author": {
            "__metadata": {
                "id": "8e4ad44e-f6f0-4dcc-92c6-78dc3d2c68af",
                "type": "SP.Data.UserInfoItem"
            },
            "Name": "i:0#.f|membership|username@contoso.onmicrosoft.com",
            "Title": "John Doe"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to modify this API call to get any user's profile data? I need a generic way to get user data by the display name. These users would be part of the "Everyone" group listed under Site Vistiors.

Comment: No you can only get the user information that is on the site users list, which is not that much more than a name and email.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It works for all the lookup fields on my table.

What about for those fields with multiple users (Type="UserMulti")? How can I get the name of all users?

Comment: does the profile picture be part of the metadata retrieved with this expand query ? I don't see any microsoft documentation on the fields which belongs to the SP.Data.UserInfoItem object.

Comment: Getting user information is pretty easy: http://www.vrdmn.com/2013/07/sharepoint-2013-get-userprofile.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below rest query to get the modified by user's title:
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Pages')/items(1)?$select=Editor/Name,Editor/Title&$expand=Editor/Id