# How to get Author field value using REST API in POST Query

Tags: rest, sharepoint, caml

I want to get the Author field from Discussion forum list in SharePoint online using REST API in POST method. I tried the below approach, it is not working.

```
var queryUrl =
  '?$select=ID,Title,Body,Author/Title,Folder/ItemCount,FieldValuesAsText/FileRef&$expand=Author,FieldValuesAsText,Folder/ItemCount';
var url =
  siteUrl +
  "/_api/Web/lists/GetByTitle('" +
  listName +
  "')/GetItems" +
  queryUrl;

var camlQuery =
  '<View><Query>' +
  getQueryParams() +
  "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='DiscussionLastUpdated' Ascending='False'/></OrderBy></Query><RowLimit>12</RowLimit></View>";

var requestData = {
  query: { __metadata: { type: 'SP.CamlQuery' }, ViewXml: camlQuery }
};

jQuery.ajax({
  url: url,
  method: 'POST',
  data: JSON.stringify(requestData),
  headers: {
    'X-RequestDigest': $('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val(),
    Accept: 'application/json; odata=verbose',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; odata=verbose'
  },
  success: function(data, status, jqXHR) {
    dfd.resolve(data);
  },
  error: function(xhr) {
    dfd.reject(xhr);
  }
});
return dfd.promise();
```

The output is like below.

[image]

Comment: This looks similar. Give it a try. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22462352/sharepoint-rest-get-user-title-in-a-single-rest-query

Comment: The article which you shared one is using GET method. I want to implement in POST method. Please suggesst me. It is working fine for GET but not for POST.

Answer (score 1):

As I have explained in [this post](https://piyushksingh.com/2018/03/04/odata-expand-not-working-sharepoint-rest-api/), **$expand** doesn't seem to work on some special columns (like People), when querying via POST. The best way will be to use the [Items API](https://piyushksingh.com/2017/08/31/retrieve-lookup-managed-metadata-and-person-or-group-data-sharepoint/).

However, if you only want to proceed with this approach then, try replacing the **queryUrl** value with the following.

```
var queryUrl ='?$select=ID,Title,Body,Folder/ItemCount,FieldValuesAsText/FileRef,FieldValuesAsText/Author&$expand=FieldValuesAsText,Folder/ItemCount';
```

Basically, what I am trying to do is that instead of directly querying the **Author** field, I am requesting it from under the **FieldValuesAsText**. Pretty much the way you have requested the **FileRef** property.